# Как сделать каждое слово в строке (игнорируя скобки) с большой буквы?

Tags: delphi

Данная функция преобразовать строку таким образом, что каждое слово начинается  с большой буквы.

```
Function UpLet(s:string):string;
var
  s_out:string;
begin
  s_out:='';
  while Pos(' ',s)<>0 do
    begin
      begin
       s_out:=s_out+AnsiUpperCase(s[1])+Copy(s,2,Pos(' ',s)-1);
       Delete(s,1,Pos(' ',s));

      end;
    end;
  if Pos(' ',s)<>Length(s) then s_out:=s_out+AnsiUpperCase(s[1])+Copy(s,2,Length(s));
   Result:=s_out;
end;
```

Сейчас данная функция обрабатывает текст такого плана

> test test test (test test)

Вот так:

> Test Test Test (test Test) - то есть слово **(test** в скобках не
>   c большой буквы

Как исправить эту функцию что бы скобки игнорировались ?

> То есть, результат на выходе: Test Test Test (Test Test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Игнорируются все "небуквы". Но между словами кроме "небукв" обязательно должны быть пробелы.

```
function UpLet(s:s tring): string;
var
  hadSpace: boolean;
begin
  hadSpace := true;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
  begin
    if hadSpace and ((s[i] in ['a'..'z']) or (s[i] in ['A'..'Z'])) then
    begin
      s[i] := AnsiUpperCase(s[i])[1];
      hadSpace := false;
    end;
    if s[i] = ' ' then
    begin
      hadSpace := true;
    end;
  end;
  result := s;
end;
```

Comment: А если текст на русском тест тест тест (тест тест) то как будет ?

Comment: @Татьяна наверное, `in 'а'..'я'`

Comment: Igor посмотрите пожалуйста (обновила тему). Сделала, но получается - английские увеличивает а русские нет. Что делаю не так ?

Comment: @Татьяна подозреваю, что `AnsiUpperCase` для многобайтных символов юникода не подходит

Comment: Если есть возможность то подскажите как тогда лучше сделать ?

Comment: @Татьяна или `Set`-операции не применимы к `Char` с значениями больше 255. Замените проверки `in` на `((s[i] >= 'а') and (s[i] <= 'я'))`, а `AnsiUpperCase` на `UpperCase`.

Comment: Сделала, но теперь Английские большие. Посмотрите что делаю не так в теме обновила.

Comment: @Татьяна Не хватает пары скобок: `if hadSpace and ( ... ) then`

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало. Кстати, заметила что если нужно обрабатывать, одновременно, русский и английский текст то AnsiUpperCase стоит оставить (если заменить на UpperCase то будут обрабатываться только английские слова).